# Where is the proper place to install Laravel projects?

Tags: php, laravel

New to Laravel, I use composer for easy install of Laravel project on my Mint 16.

Currently I use /usr/local/bin, one directory per project. This means every time I launch the composer I had to "sudo" my way to create a directory and install. Same if I want to edit contents.

I was wondering if there are standards into where is the proper location of Laravel projects and if I do will there be problems?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: In Laravel, is there a standard I should follow?

Comment: Nope, there's not. Use whatever location you find convenient. Try to avoid places where you have to sudo in though.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'll wait for more answers(suggestions) currently I transferred my project to /home/mycomputer/projectname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no real standards for where to put projects.  That said, you will most often find the following recommendations:

- `/var/www/` (or, more recently, `/var/www/html/`)
  This is the default location where Apache on Debian derivatives (like Mint) look for the "default" website.  Many people, once they have disabled the "default" website, just put all of their websites in this location.  This also means that if you keep the default website, then you can access your projects as subfolders of it. (Note, however, that your applications must be built with access from multiple paths in mind in order to take advantage of that.)
- `/srv/www/`
  `/srv` is defined in the [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) as being for "Site-specific data which are served by the system."  This could arguably include websites served, so some people put them here.
- `/home/USER/www/` (or similar things like `/home/USER/websites/`, `.../public_html/`, etc.)
  This layout was popularized by control panel software like cPanel and Plesk because it allows you to actually have each website "owned" by a particular user.  If you do development work for multiple organizations using the same computer, or if you just want to have projects in some hierarchy, this is the best one to use.  If you are using Apache as your webserver and yyou have `mod_userdir` enabled, this will allow you to access all of your sites at `http://example.com/~USER/foldername` (with the caveat about paths mentioned in the note above).
  One good example of the use of this location is Laravel's [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/homestead) development environment, which defaults to putting sites in `/home/USER/Code/`. (However, I do not consider this an official "recommendation" from Laravel that this is how it *should* be done; rather it's just a "we do it this way for convenience".)

Comment: I talked to somebody who is using GitHub repo since he uses different machines for different location. To which I am considerably be using later. Does that fall under /srv/www? or somewhere else?

Comment: The fact that you would use Git doesn't change anything - you can still pot it anywhere you want. Git does not dictate location on your hard drive.